# Usage of たかが not as adverb

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

The sentence was like this:

> 目の前にたかだパフェが置かれただけなのにキャッキヤツとはしゃいでいる。彼女に言わせれば「***何がたかがよ***!」という感じなのだろうが。

I'm familiar with the grammar of "たかが + N" (it's just a + N). However, the way たかが was used herein `何がたかがよ` seems a bit strange to me. Can I take it as something like:

> It's no big deal

Thank you for taking the time. Have a great day, everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

何が～だ (or 何が～よ, 何が～さ, etc) is a way to say something along the lines of "Talk about ～!", "Who said ～!", "I can't believe [someone] said ～". She just repeated たかが said by someone else.

Comment: The complete sentence is like this: `彼女に言わせれば「何がたかがよ!」という感じなのだろうが。` (たかが was not mentioned before according to the context)

Comment: The one before this sentence mentioned `目の前にたかだパフェが置かれただけなのにキャッキヤツとはしゃいでいる`. There is a phrase `たかだ`, not sure if it relates to `たかが`. Does anything click?

Comment: What's たかだ? It's most likely a typo for たかが?

Comment: it could be. That makes sense because I'm also confused with the phrase `目の前にたかだパフェ`. If it was `たかがパフェ` (it's just a parfait), then two sentences linked together. Although the content was extracted from an official novel, so I'm wondering if it's really a typo. The link to my related question here https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/83397/29550

Comment: The question was updated to provide more information upon the context

Comment: @elPsyChris Unless there is really 高田パフェ in the novel, it's just a typo. (And if it's really 高田パフェ, then 何がたかがよ becomes a typo...)

Comment: 「たかが」ですね。　https://scontent-itm1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/134696621_3602578203183370_6682303825759233271_n.jpg?_nc_cat=106&ccb=2&_nc_sid=730e14&_nc_ohc=Rywri_OagYcAX9CJvad&_nc_ht=scontent-itm1-1.xx&oh=65f0215ebbfe3f3c10081200a6dda1ea&oe=60130EB9

Comment: @Chocolate yes, that's the one