# 目の前にたかだ usage in a sentence

Tags: particles, syntax

> 目の前***にたかだパフェ***が置かれただけなのにキャッキヤツとはしゃいでいる。彼女に言わせれば「何がたかがよ!」という感じなのだろうが。

The part that confused me is: `目の前にたかだパフェ...`

I took it as `目の前　似た　佳だ パフェ` (An excellent parfait like the one before her now).

However, the part of using `だ` linking a な-ADJ and a NOUN struck me a little bit odd. Am I wrong and what is the correct way to translate this sentence?

Thank you

Comment: Should be a typo of たか**が**パフェ.

Comment: Yeah, it makes a lot more sense @Chocolate

Comment: この小説ですよね。　https://scontent-itm1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/134696621_3602578203183370_6682303825759233271_n.jpg?_nc_cat=106&ccb=2&_nc_sid=730e14&_nc_ohc=Rywri_OagYcAX9CJvad&_nc_ht=scontent-itm1-1.xx&oh=65f0215ebbfe3f3c10081200a6dda1ea&oe=60130EB9

Comment: yeah, that's it

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood it. I do believe that たかだ is a name (maybe the patissiere's name or perhaps it is a type of parfaits since google search seems to suggest that) hard to say without context.
The sentence can be parsed as: "目の前に    たかだパフェ    置かれただけ"
Which means: in front of you( or him/her) only a takada parfait was placed

Comment: Interesting. Is there any chance that `たかだ` somehow relating to `たかが` (it's just a parfait) because the context as a whole suggested nothing about a `Takada parfait`

Comment: The question was updated to provide more information on the context. Hope it helps